# CSS Selection: toggling between nth items within an ancestor class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have two nested classes within a common ancestor like:

```
<div class="css-18e3th9">
  <div class="x1">
    <div class="x2">
    ..
      <div class="css-t0qh0m">
      </div>
    ..
    </div>
  </div>
  ..

  ..
  <div class="x1">
    <div class="x2">
    ..
      <div class="css-t0qh0m">
      </div>
    ..
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Lots of divs & classes in between the common ancestor (`css-18e3th9`) and the targeted class: `css-t0qh0m`. I can't count all of the in-between classes and they may change dynamically over time.

I'm seeking to style the targeted classes, `css-t0qh0m`, differently. How to I select each independently? Currently there are only two targeted classes, but there may be more in the future.

Comment: Normally you would assign both/all of them an individual `id="somethingunique"` , and then style based on that (`#somethingunique { color: blue; }`), but i'm getting the impression you don't control the markup perhaps ?

Comment: @Raxi correct - I have to adjust the markup after it's produced.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, it won't be possible with just CSS then, as there is nothing to anchor to and while they do have a common ancestor somewhere up the line, they don't share a parent so the usual `::nth-child`-type selectors aren't an option here.  It can however be done using javascript, if that is an option for you.

Comment: @Raxi Thanks for the help. Is there the ability to select the nth `id` in the whole document? Such as, if they both share the same id, and they are the only two `divs` that do so?

Comment: `id` attributes may never be repeated. There are `nth-last-of-type`-selectors and such, but none will suit the scenario that you have here, (that selector for example isn't combined with a class so it'd then count based on **all** `<div>`s, not just the `css-t0qh0m` ones)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, i don't think there is a pure CSS method to accomplish this (seeing as the html markup is out of your hands).
Should you be able to add javascript though, then something like this should solve the problem:

```
let items = document.querySelectorAll('div.css-18e3th9');
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
  items[i].id = 'autorenamed-css-' + (i + 1);
}
```

That would give the first `div.css-18e3th9` an `id=autorenamed-css-1` attribute, the next one `id=autorenamed-css-2`, and so forth. That way you can apply your styles like

```
#autorenamed-css-1 { background-color: red;  }
#autorenamed-css-2 { background-color: blue; }
```